# heroku like deploy tool for vps

Tags: linux, heroku, vps

Deploying your web app to heroku is easy

What I want to know it is there any open source tools installed on your linux server so you can have the same deploying experience, since heroku buildpacks is all open source.

Answer (score 0):

[Dokku](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/) is single-host version of Heroku. It allows you to push Heroku-compatible applications to via git.